# Tensorflow 2.0 (Python) - Parrallel Loop in Graph Mode

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Suppose there are variables in different shapes:

```
tvs = model.trainable_variables
```

In case one wants to apply some custom optimization operations to these variables, each variable should have its own graph:

```
ops = []
for idx, tv in enumerate(tvs):
    @tf.function
    def op(xs):
        # Some operations
        tv.assign_add(xs[idx])
    ops.append(op)
```

and then apply these operations somewhere else (e.g. in training loop):

```
@tf.function
def step_ops(xs):
    for op in ops : op(xs)
```

in which `step_ops` takes list of tensors (e.g., gradients of variables) as input.

The question is, will op insides ops runs parallelly in step_ops?

If not, how to get it run parallelly? Or are there any better approaches to achieve this?

Many thanks.